# Using = in tcolorbox title parameter

Tags: tcolorbox

I have found I am unable to use an equals sign in the titles of tcolorboxes.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=foo\=bar]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Using a normal equals sign messes with the parameter syntax, and using `\={}` causes it to be a high horizontal line over any subsequent character.

Is there any way to make it show an equals sign correctly?

Comment: `\=` is a macron accent command, use `title={foo=bar}`  to hide an =

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That shows the equals sign correctly but it also a does weird thing with the spacing between words.

`title={nmap -sV --script=vulscan/vulscan.nse --script-args vulscandb=cve.csv --disable-arp-ping 192.168.1.0/24}` is the actual title I am using.

Comment: that would be a different question and the spacing depends on fonts and page size and other stuff you haven't shown (it is always best to provide a complete small test document in the question)  but the issues ar completely separate, presumably you get somilar space issue if you had used a simpler character  with say `-` instead of `=` so theanswer to yiour parsing question is to use `{..}` but you can ask a new question about the typesetting if you provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\=` is a macron accent command. In common with most other commands taking a key-value list, you can use braces to hide commas or equals signs in a value, so

```
 title={foo=bar}
```